# I want to disable CSRF for a webhook endpoint in webflux/kotlin/spring boot 3 app

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-webflux, csrf

I have the following code:

```
@Bean
fun configure(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
    // @formatter:off
    return http
        .authorizeExchange { it.pathMatchers(GET, *ALLOW_LIST_STATIC_RESOURCES).permitAll() }
        .authorizeExchange { it.pathMatchers(GET, *ALLOW_LIST_VIEWS).permitAll() }
        .authorizeExchange { it.pathMatchers(GET, *ALLOW_LIST_RESOURCES).permitAll() }
        .authorizeExchange { it.pathMatchers(POST, *ALLOW_LIST_API_POST).permitAll() }
        .authorizeExchange { it.pathMatchers(DELETE, *ALLOW_LIST_API_DELETE).permitAll() }
        .formLogin { it.disable() }
        .headers { headers -> headers.contentTypeOptions { } }
        .headers { headers -> headers.frameOptions { it.mode(XFrameOptionsServerHttpHeadersWriter.Mode.DENY) } }
        .headers { headers -> headers.xssProtection { it.disable() } }
        .headers { headers -> headers.permissionsPolicy { it.policy("accelerometer=(), ambient-light-sensor=(), autoplay=(), camera=(), encrypted-media=(), fullscreen=(), geolocation=(), gyroscope=(), interest-cohort=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), midi=(), payment=(), usb=(), vr=(), xr-spatial-tracking=()") } }
        .headers { headers -> headers.contentSecurityPolicy { it.policyDirectives(contentSecurityPolicy) } }
        .build()
    // @formatter:on
}
```

I want to disable CSRF protection ONLY for the endpoint "/app/webhook", but I can't find a way.
I can't do : `.csrf { it.ignoringAntMatchers("/app/webhook") }` as `ignoringAntMatchers` doesn't exist.
How can I do it? I want CSRF to apply to all but that endpoint. I think Spring applies CSRF protection for all modifying calls (excluding then GETs) by default, so those webhooks call would be blocked because they come from external providers.
Using `NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher` inside `csrf.requireCsrfProtectionMatcher` doesn't work either.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT 1**:

If I use this code:

```
.csrf { csrf -> 
csrf.requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(disabledUrlForCSRF()) }.build()

fun disabledUrlForCSRF(): AndServerWebExchangeMatcher = AndServerWebExchangeMatcher(
    CsrfWebFilter.DEFAULT_CSRF_MATCHER,
    NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
        ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(POST, "/app/webhook")
    )
```

It works

**EDIT 2**:

I made it work also by writing it like so (cleaned up a little bit for clarity):

```
@Bean
fun configure(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
    // @formatter:off
    return http
        .securityMatcher(
            isNot(  ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(POST,"/app/webhook")
            )
        )
        .authorizeExchange { it.pathMatchers(OPTIONS).permitAll() }
        .authorizeExchange { it.pathMatchers(POST, *ALLOW_LIST_API_POST).permitAll() }
        .authorizeExchange { it.pathMatchers(DELETE, *ALLOW_LIST_API_DELETE).permitAll() }
        .authorizeExchange { it.pathMatchers(GET).permitAll() }
        .authorizeExchange { it.anyExchange().denyAll() }
        .httpBasic { it.disable() }
        .formLogin { it.disable() }.securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
        .build()
    // @formatter:on
}

fun isNot(matcher: ServerWebExchangeMatcher): ServerWebExchangeMatcher {
    return NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(matcher)
}
```

Three important things here:

- if CSRF is enabled (so without the csrf.disable()) it creates a SESSION cookie even if I explicitly tell him not to do so with the NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository thingy.
- I added the matcher for GETs on all endpoints with `permitAll()`, to redirect the user to a custom error page in case the user browse to a non-existing page for example, which it didn't happen when using the `anyExchange().denyAll()` line only.

But these are not related to the topic.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you authenticating? You have explicitly disabled `formLogin()` (which you don't need to do) but you haven't specified an authentication mechanism. Also, are you aware of the Kotlin DSL? It would clean up and make your code semantically correct, which it doesn't look to be right now.

Comment: Yeah I am aware but I am fine with what I have coded. The application has no authentication, all users are anonymous. I don't need authentication but it doesn't matter for the topic at hand

Comment: Ok, using the negated matcher you demonstrate works. So if you can provide a complete sample, I can take a closer look but based on what you've provided here I can't reproduce.

Comment: I updated the question. With the previous code I get FORBIDDEN on the only endpoint where I don't want the csrf protection to apply, so apparently the Negated filter doesn't filter that endpoint out. Anyways I have updated the question with a solution that works but not sure if it is secure and best practise to be honest since I am not a security expert.

Comment: Alright I see now what you mean, I permitted /wehbook/app instead of /app/webhook, error was on my side indeed. So indeed the first solution work as well.